# Ebean creation from JSON: referencing sibling property

Tags: mysql, json, playframework, ebean

Using PlayFramework 2.3.8 and MySQL, I have a simplified object structure:

```
@Entity
@Table("ParentTable")
public class ParentClass extends AbstractModel{
  // ID is generated by MySQL, AI column

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="child_1_id")
  public List<Child1> childs1 = new ArrayList<>(); // I am aware of the correct plural of the word 'child', I just don't care :)

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="child_2_id")
  public List<Child2> childs2 = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table("Child1Table")
public class Child1Class extends AbstractModel{
  // ID is generated by MySQL, AI column
  // BUT I WANT TO REFERENCE THIS ID FROM CHILD2!

  @Column(name="some_property")
  String some_property;
}

@Entity
@Table("Child2Table")
public class Child2Class extends AbstractModel{
  // ID is generated by MySQL, AI column

  @Column(name="child1_id_reference")
  int child1_id_reference;
}
```

Given this simple model, I would like to import data through a JSON string and further create the objects with their relations:

```
Example JSON:
{
childs1:[
  {
  "some_property": "foo"
  },{
  "some_property": "bar"
  }
],
childs2:[
  {
  "child1_id_reference": ??? // should reference to the ID of "foo"
  },{
  "child1_id_reference": ??? // should reference to the ID of "bar"
  }
]
}
```

Eventually, this JSON gets serialized and pumped into the DB within PlayFramework:

```
JsonNode json = Json.parse(jsonIn); // jsonIn = the JSON above as String
ParentClass = Json.fromJson(json, ParentClass.class);
```

It works perfectly fine except for the child1_id_reference properties. Obviously, I can't know the future IDs of "foo" and "bar" while I write the JSON.

So the question is: can I somehow link those, referencing to a sibling (sometimes even the child of a sibling, in the actual data model) within JSON?

Or can you think of a workaround? One idea could be to give the Child1Class a property, which holds a value that is unique within its ParentClass. After PlayFramework creates the actual objects, Child1Class has it's IDs and Child2Class can, in an UPDATE statement, reference to this ID.

Could this work, or am I completely lost here? The "worst case" is that I have to hook up Child1Class and Child2Class manually after creating from the JSON input. Thanks in advance!